# Do Australians say "down north"?

Tags: australian-english, geography

I noticed some maps from the southern hemisphere are "reversed" with the south pole on top.

Which makes me wonder, are there places in the southern hemisphere where the concept of "down" is presumed to mean north instead of south? For example, would someone say: "Yea I went down north for a bit to Ireland"

Just curious.

Comment: Those maps are for fun so if you were having a bit of fun including joking around with such a map then we might well say something like that, otherwise no.

Comment: @hippietrail & 1 other: You mean **not**.

Comment: Why is this considered better here than on [travel.se] ?

Answer (score 11):

The maps you see with south at the top are generally considered novelties, and are not seriously considered. The worldwide convention for maps is to orient north at the top.

I have never heard the expression "down north" when referring to the northern hemisphere. A [Google Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=down+north%2C+down+south&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdown%20north%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdown%20south%3B%2Cc0) shows that sometimes people say "down north" when living in an area where the rivers generally run northward toward the sea (such as arctic Canada).

Comment: For additional information, there's an excellent article about [How the north ended up on top of the map](http://america.aljazeera.com/opinions/2014/2/maps-cartographycolonialismnortheurocentricglobe.html).

Comment: I looked at an arbitrary subset of ngram appearances of "down north", and 8/10 of them were things like "helicopter had gone down north of" and "are now driving down North Korea's". Only 1 usage was (possibly) similar to the usage described here: "to move down north of the Neuse". So I would take the ngram comparison between "down south" and "down north" with a rather gigantic grain of salt (as in "down north" is probably much, much less common than the 5% of "down south" that the graph suggests).